# Apply rewrite rule if url not contains certain path

Tags: angularjs, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

i've written this rewrite rule for my AngularJs application that use html5 routing.

The rewrite url is this:

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^.*\.(jpg|css|js|gif|png|html|woff)$
 RewriteRule ^ index.html  [L]
```

I want that all the URL that contains path **/old/** and with path **/images/** aren't rewritten!

Someone can help me i tried to add rewrite condition like this :

```
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/old/
```

But it doesn't work!

Regards,
Lorenzo

**UPDATE**

If you're using AngularJS with routing use target="_self" on `<a>` element that has link in the same domain but aren't under the angular routing!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your third `RewriteCond` is useless since you're already checking for existing files in first condition.

Also, if you're in a subdirectory (like `/old/` or something, you should add a `RewriteBase` or a leading slash to your `index.html`. Otherwise it will look in current directory (404 error probably).

You can replace your code by this one

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(old|images)/ [NC]
RewriteRule . /index.html  [L]
```